# Combine two angularFire (Realtime database) list objects to form a new observable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I have two angularFireList observables appointments and patients. Appointment contain patientId. I want to take all appointment data and corresponding patient data and combine them to form new AppointedPatient[] observable. Below code was working fine with HttpClient, but when I updated to use AngularFire, it's no longer working.

```
  getAppointments() {
    this.appointmentService.fetchAllAppointments()
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(appointments => {
        const appointedPatients: AppointedPatient[] = [];

        for (const appointment of appointments) {
          const appointmentDate = new Date(appointment.appointmentDateTime);
          const appointmentDateOnly  = new Date(appointmentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
          const newAppointment$: any = this.patientsService.getPatient(appointment.patientId)
            .pipe(
              switchMap((patient) => of(new AppointedPatient(
                  appointment.appointmentId,
                  patient.firstName,
                  patient.lastName,
                  patient.address,
                  patient.casePaperNumber,
                  patient.mobileNumber,
                  appointment.appointmentDateTime,
                  appointmentDateOnly
                ))
              )
            );
          appointedPatients.push(newAppointment$);
        }
        return forkJoin(appointedPatients);
      })
    ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

Comment: the code seems fine though

Comment: yes... but after subscribing, nothing is happening.. it not even printing null to console... If you have any other approach to handle such scenario please share

Comment: try set break points in various places inside switchMap and see whether the source observable is actually getting executed. then dig into the forkJoin item observable and check for the samething

Comment: It's fetching appointments and patients correctly... it also getting newAppointment$ observable... can't figure out it is right or wrong?

Comment: try return forkJoin(appointedPatients).pipe(tap(console.log),catchError(e=>{console.error(e);return of(e)}), maybe there where error

Comment: Put breakpoint after push, inspect the results there if they are good the problem is futher down.

Comment: I don't know why but it worked with combineLatest instead of forkJoin.